# Which public Git repository services support the `--filter` option?

Tags: git

I have a need for using the `--filter` option of `git clone` to filter out large blobs using `--filter=blob:limit=<n>`.

However, GitHub, which I assumed supported this option seems to ignore it, without giving a warning. In particular, `--filter=blob:none` still clones ordinary text files.

In comparison, BitBucket gives the following warning, when attempting to use the `--filter` option:

```
$ git clone --filter=blob:none 'https://example.com/openshift-demo-project.git'
Cloning into 'openshift-demo-project'...
warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
```

Which public Git repository services, like GitHub, supports the `--filter` option?

Comment: GitLab does. See [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html).

Comment: GitHub does indeed support this feature.

Comment: @bk2204 - Why does `clone --filter=blob:none ...` include files then?

Comment: Objects are fetched on demand as needed to check out the repository.  So even though you asked it to not clone any blobs, Git requested the server to send the small number of blobs it needed to do a checkout.  Other blobs still have not been fetched.

Comment: So, only the blobs (files) needed to checkout `HEAD` was fetched? All other blobs for other commits aren’t fetched to the object database, which they would be without the `--filter` option? I should use `--no-checkout` to not fetch all the blobs for `HEAD`?